# XAMPP #1045 - Access denied for user

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

Recently tried update the sql user password via phpmyadmin and now I get this error:

> #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I've searched dozens of stack posts and none of the solutions that people have accepted seem to work for me. I've tried editing the phpMyAdmin `config.inc.php` to set a new password, and left it blank entirely - with no success.

Currently the config file looks like:

```
/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';

/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';

/* User for advanced features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';
```

I'm at a complete loss now. Any help appreciated. I thought I knew the password (it was something I had set not long ago) but upon trying to install a new instance of a CMS for a new database, it wouldn't accept the password so hence I tried to make a new one).

I've tried changing the auth type:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
```

Which gives me the ability to manually enter the details now set. But it still says their incorrect, somehow...

Comment: change the `auth_type` to `http`, e.g.

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply the new password in the config file at this line:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'yournewpassword';
```

if you can't remember your root password the follow the instructions [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html) to reset it.